# Alert Prompt issue in Jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validate for my form.

If i submit without anything filled, the error message gets consolidated and shows in a single alert prompt.

The issue is after the consolidated alert, it keeps on saying the very first field alert and it is definitely annoying to users. Can you help me avoid this?

```
jQuery(".ContactForm").validate({
        ignore: ":hidden",
        rules: {
            Location: {
                required: true
            },
            Program: {
                required: true
            },
            firstname: {
                required: true,
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true,
            },
            zip: {
                required: true,
                checkZipsValue: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            dayphone: {
                required: true,
                phoneUS: true,
                checkPhoneValue: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                validEmail:true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Location: "Please select a location.",
            Program: "Please select a program.",
            firstname: "Please enter your first name.",
            lastname: "Please enter your last name.",
            dayphone: "Please enter a valid phone number.",
            zip: "Please enter a valid Zip code.",
            email: "Please enter a valid email.",
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            //alert(error.text());

        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        var error = ''; jQuery.each(errorList,function(i, a){error += a.message + "\n";}); if(error.length > 0){window.alert(error);}
    },
});
```

Comment: the thing is the showErros call everytime for every fields so it is better that u declare the error variable outside of this validate function and merge all the the strings in that and after all fields are validate just show the alert with all errors.

Comment: what is the error in the browser console?

Comment: No Errors in console.

Comment: @Dhaval Purohit, Thanks for your feedback. I m new to programming. Can you tell me how to deal it. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the relevant rendered HTML markup of this form.

Comment: ok i have answered the whole code please check it out

Answer (score 0):

following code is to show the all message in one alert,

kindly note that chekphonevalue,validemail,checkzipsvalue are your additional methods it have no concern with the jquery validator plugin so dont forget to add it in the validator.

```
<form id="myform" action="#">

    <input type="text" name="Location">
    <input type="text" name="Program">
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <input type="text" name="zip">
    <input type="text" name="dayphone">
    <input type="text" name="email">

    <input type="submit" value="email">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var errors;
jQuery("#myform").validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
    ignore: ":hidden",
    rules: {
        Location: {
            required: true
        },
        Program: {
            required: true
        },
        firstname: {
            required: true,
        },
        lastname: {
            required: true,
        },
        zip: {
            required: true,
            checkZipsValue: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        dayphone: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true,
            checkPhoneValue: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Location: "Please select a location.",
        Program: "Please select a program.",
        firstname: "Please enter your first name.",
        lastname: "Please enter your last name.",
        dayphone: "Please enter a valid phone number.",
        zip: "Please enter a valid Zip code.",
        email: "Please enter a valid email.",
    },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        errors="";
        jQuery.each(errorList,function(key,item){
            errors+=item.message+"\n";
        });
        alert(errors);
    },
});
</script>
```